# Why RTS/CTS do not solve completely the hidden terminal problem and exposed terminal problem?

Tags: wireless, mac

I was doing some reading online and textbooks about the RTS/CTS protocol for wireless transmission. Although, the textbook that I read said that the hidden terminal (and exposed terminal) is solved by RTS/CTS, online I saw that actually RTS/CTS protocol does not solve completely the problem. But only reduces is.

The protocol seems pretty neat and to me it looks as if the problem is solved. What am I missing here, why multiple sources claim that the problem is not solved?!

Are there hard assumption underneath the whole protocol?

Comment: Huh?  How do you expect us to know what you think this *"hidden/exposed terminal problem"* is?

Comment: hidden terminal problem and exposed terminal problem are particularly famous topics in the field of Wireless Communication especially when MAC layer protocols are considered. Or am I wrong?

Comment: This question would probably fit better on serverfault or superuser SE.

Comment: I don't see how a MAC layer protocol is related to severfault or superuser which are SE oriented on the practical side of computer stuff

Comment: I don't get why the question is put on hold when obviously it has an answer. The hidden terminal and exposed terminal problem are popular enough in the field of wireless communication, and have been addressed heavily in the design of cellular systems and 802.11 standards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, it should be noted that RTS/CTS referred to in the question have nothing to do with hardware wires such as the RTS/CTS wires frequently used for UART handshaking.  That having been said, this is a low-level radio-communication problem and would appear to be about as topical here as would be questions about things like XBee.

The "hidden/exposed" terminal problem relates the fact that it's possible to have three nodes, X, Y, and Z, such that Y is close enough to X to receive data when Z is silent, and Z is simultaneously close enough to Y to jam communications from X, but far enough away from X that X cannot detect it.

In the general case, Z will have no way of knowing when someone might be sending information to Y, and thus Z will have no way of knowing when his transmissions would jam those of someone else.  If X is sending a small packet to Y, it's cheaper for X to simply send it and be prepared to retransmit if it gets jammed, than it would be to try to prevent such jamming.  If X is sending a larger packet, however, it's useful to have X start with a small packet that tells Y to expect a larger one, and have Y respond with a small packet that indicates that it's expecting to receive the larger packet.  This has a few useful effects.  Chief among them:

1. If Y cannot hear a small packet from X, there's no reason for X to send a big packet.  Having X refrain from sending a big packet helps avoid cluttering up the airwaves with useless data that would possibly block or collide with other transmissions.
2. If Z hears Y say that it's expecting data from X, then Z will know that it should avoid transmitting on that particular channel during the time the transmission is expected to take place.

The RTS/CTS protocol is not a panacea.  It can make it so that collisions are unlikely on larger data blocks, but does nothing to solve the problem of collisions with smaller data blocks [fortunately, small-block collisions are generally less costly].  Further, even if both X and Y advertise the fact that X is going to send data to Y, and even if Z is close enough to X and Y to jam their transmissions, there's no guarantee that Z will actually hear the advertisement from X or Y.  For example, Z might be communicating with node Q, which is out of range of X and Y, and Q might send data to Z at the same time as X and Y are sending their advertisements.  In that case, because Z would not have heard X and Y saying they expected to talk to each other, Z would have no reason to hold off its transmissions on their behalf.

Fundamentally, wireless communication is plagued with a certain asymmetry: if A hears something from B, it can know that B sent it, but if A doesn't hear anything that doesn't imply that that B didn't send anything.  Conceptually, it should be possible for a receiver to distinguish between "silence" and "indecipherable noise", and figure that if A gets silence (as opposed to noise) then B can't have sent anything, but I am unaware of protocols that take advantage of such distinctions.